# Get the biggest value from a dictionary of tuples

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the biggest value from a dictionary of tuples:

```py
stats = {'a':(1000, 2000), 'b':(3000, 200), 'c':(100, 100), 'd':(100, 100), 'e':(100, 2000), 'f':(1000, 2000)}
```

So far I can get the biggest values from the tuple, from index 0 or 1:

```
print(max(stats.values(), key=itemgetter(1))[1])
```

but I can't see how I could get the key, so it prints:

```py
e 2000
```

Comment: Isn't the biggest value in the tuples `3000` or are you looking for the second item of the tuple? In that case why not the key `'a'` or `'f'`?

Comment: what do you mean by biggest value?

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev I'm looking for the second value in the tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> print(max(stats.items(), key=lambda i : i[1][1]))
('a', (1000, 2000))
```

If you just want to print the key name and the second value of the tuple, try this :

```
>>> max_pair = max(stats.items(), key=lambda i : i[1][1])
>>> print(max_pair[0], max_pair[1][1])
a 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
max_key = max(stats, key=lambda k: stats[k])
print(max_key, stats[max_key])
# prints `b (3000, 200)`
```

This will print `b (3000, 200)` as by default the first item in the tuple is used for sorting.

If you want to sort for the second item in the tuple:

```py
max_key = max(stats, key=lambda k: stats[k][1])
print(max_key, stats[max_key])
```

In your example this prints `a (1000, 2000)` as there are multiple tuples which have the same maximum value 2000.

Comment: I've added duplicate to the example to make it hard on myself. First I wanted to print the key and the value. Thanks!